# Flask: current_app AttributeError if field doesn't exist

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I try to create two decorators for Flask decorating a simple function. Both decorators need to have access to the same field/attribute on current_app. Also the decorated function needs access to this same attribute. But I want to test if this field already exists and get it's value in either decorator. Testing for existance does work if it already exists, but it returns a AttributeError if it doesn't exist yet. For example: Testing for 'None' or using hasattr/getattr gives a AttributeError if the field doesn't exist.

For example:

```
if current_app.exists is None:
```

Gives:

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

Is try/catch the proper way to handle this?

```
def first(org_func):
    @wraps(org_func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            current_app.exists = current_app.exists + ' and then first'
        except AttributeError:
            current_app.exists = 'first'
        print(current_app.exists)
        return org_func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

def second(org_func):
    @wraps(org_func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            current_app.exists = current_app.exists + ' and then second'
        except AttributeError:
            current_app.exists = 'second'
        print(current_app.exists)
        return org_func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

@first    
@second  
def get(self):
    print('original function calling ' + current_app.exists)
    return {'message': 'ok'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin function `hasattr` for this. It does essentially the same thing as your decorator

```
hasattr(obj, name, /)
    Return whether the object has an attribute with the given name.

    This is done by calling getattr(obj, name) and catching AttributeError.
```

For example:

```
if hasattr(current_app, 'exists'):
    print("current_app has 'exists' attribute")
else:
    print("current_app does not have 'exists' attribute")
```

Alternatively, you can use `getattr` with a default value, for example:

```
exists_first = getattr(current_app, 'exists', 'first')
# if current_app has an 'exists' attribute, then exists_first == current_app.exists
# if current_app does NOT have an 'exists' attribue, then exists_first == 'first'
exists_second = getattr(current_app, 'exists', 'second')
# if current_app has an 'exists' attribute, then exists_second == current_app.exists
# if current_app does NOT have an 'exists' attribue, then exists_second == 'second'
```